# How can reduce the number of branches/if statements in my kernels?

Tags: c++, cuda, control-flow, idioms

Is there a smart way to reduce the number of the `if statements` inside a CUDA's kernel?

I am writing an application that will calculate a many-body Hamiltonian (simulation of a quantum system). Calculations depend highly on `conditional expressions`.

The reason behind why I want to reduce those statements is because they introduce performance overhead. (whole `warp` enters each option of `if(){} else if(){}` statement - if condition is not met, the `thread`, for a given time, remains inactive).

**Question:**

 1. Will `switch()` statement resolve the issue?

 2. The code below is meant to represent a general idea:

```
class tag_option_1 {};
class tag_option_2 {};
class tag_option_3 {};

template<typename T> __device__
int cal_something(int ab, int cd)
{
    return -12345; // error value. default case is an error.
};

template<> __device__
int cal_something<tag_option_1>(int ab, int cd)
{
    // return something
}

template<> __device__
int cal_something<tag_option_2>(int ab, int cd)
{
    // return something
}

template<> __device__
int cal_something<tag_option_3>(int ab, int cd)
{
    // return something
}

////////////////////////////////
// version #1:

__global__
void calc_hamiltonian(int * foo, int * bar)
{
    unsigned int tid = /* calce thread index*/;

    // do something... 

    if (/* condition */)
    {
        cal_something<tag_option_1>(foo[tid], bar[tid]);
    }
    else if(/* condition */)
    {
        cal_something<tag_option_2>(foo[tid], bar[tid]);
    }
    else if(/* condition */)
    {
        cal_something<tag_option_3>(foo[tid], bar[tid]);
    }
    // no default case.

    // do something... 
}

////////////////////////////////
// version #2:

// "magical" way to select a version:
// variant is meant to be something like "boost::variant" but implementented without a single "if" statement.
// This "magical" step is meant to be resolved at compile time.
__devcie__
variant <tag_option_1, tag_option_2, tag_option_3> 
version_selector(int ab, int cd)
{
    // magic happens here.
}


__global__
void calc_hamiltonian(int * foo, int * bar)
{
    unsigned int tid = /* calce thread index*/;

    // do something... 

    cal_something <version_selector(foo[tid], bar[tid])> (foo[tid], bar[tid]);

    // do something... 
}
```

Is there a way to implement a `version #2` of the example above, or it is impossible in `CUDA C/C++`?

Comment: Any evaluation where you make a decision based on the result is branching code. This includes, `if`-statements, `switch`-statements, ternaries, loop-conditions, and so on. All of these are poorly supported by the GPU :(

Comment: You are making a number of assumptions which are not necessarily true. CUDA GPUs support predicated execution, and the compiler will not necessarily emit code which will produce instruction replay for code which emits branching (be that if, switch, or any other similar construct).

Comment: Apart from @talonmies comments, the only advice I have seen is to attempt to organize your code (really, data) such that branching occurs on warp boundaries.  If such a thing is possible, your code can still take advantage of conditional execution, but without paying as much of a penalty for it, as would be the case for intra-warp branching.  Furthermore, anything that groups like paths together (such as sorting of input data, for example) may help with the net cost of warp divergence.  Usually we tackle this problem when the profiler indicates it is a top-level issue to address.

Comment: In addition to predicated execution pointed out by @talonmies, GPUs also support select-type instructions (e.g. `SEL`) that the CUDA compiler uses to avoid branches. My standing recommendation is: Write CUDA code in a natural style and do not worry about branches in source code until the profiler tells you they are responsible for a performance bottleneck due to divergence. If you presented a concrete example (with code we can compile), the question might be answerable. Otherwise, I consider it "too broad".

Comment: @JonathanMee: That's not always true, see my answer.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: See example in my answer.

Comment: @njuffa: Referred to `slct` in my answer. I actually don't think it is too broad.

Answer (score 3):

I generally agree with @njuffa's recommendation of not trying to twist your natural coding style artificially, and that you should be after performance (and readability and maintainability) rather than counting branches in your source code. Especially since the compiler might make them go away sometimes.

Having said that...

A few common-wisdom "smart" ways to reduce the number of branches (in CUDA and in general):

### 1. Arrange for conditions to be checked in advance, preferably at compile time

Explanation by example. Version 1:

```
 void foo(int* a, bool cond) {
     ...
     for(int i = 0; i < lots; i++) {
         if (cond) do_stuff()
         else do_other_stuff();
     }
     ...
 }

 bool cond = check_stuff();
 foo(data, cond);
```

Version 2:

```
 void foo(int* a, bool cond) {
     ...
     if (cond) {
         for(int i = 0; i < lots; i++) { do_stuff(); }
     }
     else {
         for(int i = 0; i < lots; i++) { do_other_stuff(); }
     }
     ...
 }

 bool cond = check_stuff();
 foo(data, cond);
```

Version 3:

```
 template <bool Cond>
 void foo(int* a) {
     ...
     if (cond) {
         for(int i = 0; i < lots; i++) { do_stuff(); }
     }
     else {
         for(int i = 0; i < lots; i++) { do_other_stuff(); }
     }
     ...
 }

 bool cond = check_stuff();
 if (cond) foo<true>(data) else foo<false>(data);
```

Version 4:

```
 template <bool Cond>
 void foo(int* a) {
     ...
     for(int i = 0; i < lots; i++) {
         if (cond) do_stuff()
         else do_other_stuff();
     }
     ...
 }

 bool cond = check_stuff();
 if (cond) foo<true>(data) else foo<false>(data);
```

And the nice thing about versions 3 and 4 is that while it *looks* like they have a branch, they actually don't - the compiler either takes only the "then" statement, or only the "else" statement, but not both in the same function.

Going from version 1 to version 2 is something the compiler might be kind enough to do for you; but sometimes it's not as simple as in the example and you have to take care of it yourself. Going from version 2 to version 3 is something the compiler will never do for you. Going to version 4 is a bit like coming full-circle, since it looks like version 1, with no code duplication - but the branch is actually still gone.

#### 1.1 Consider templating kernels on block size

This is not always - in fact, not often - useful, but there's a well-known example given by Mark Harris in his [presentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) on optimizing parallel reductions with CUDA. Have a look at  optimization #6 in slides 24-27. But don't try something like that - which is ugly and somewhat brittle - unless you've carefully *timed* your execution to make sure it's worth it.

### 2. Make behaviors diverge in *data* rather than in *control flow*

Version 1:

```
 void foo(int* a, int *b) {
     ...
     if (check(a[global_thread_index]) { b[global_thread_index]++; }
 }
```

Version 2:

```
 void foo(int* a, int *b) {
     ...
     b[global_thread_index] += check(a[global_thread_index]);
 }
```

(assuming check returns a boolean, or an integer 0 on failure and 1 on success.)

Here I'm not so sure what the CUDA compiler will do; plus, you're paying a readability penalty by writing this code and arguably breaking the ["principle of least astonishment"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). But you can find less contrived examples.

#### 2.1 Limit branches to trinary-operation choices of value

There's also a Version 3:

```
 void foo(int* a, int *b) {
     ...
     b[global_thread_index] = check(a[global_thread_index]) ? 1 : 0;
 }
```

Now, this still has a branch - the trinary operator is just a shorthand for an "if", but if you can get your code to this state, divergence will be limited to a single statement and each branch, and perhaps even less, if the CUDA compiler manages to use the [slct PTX statement](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#comparison-and-selection-instructions-slct):

> **slct**
>
> Select one source operand, based on the sign of the third operand.

this "wraps up" the semantics of a branch into the combinatorial logic for a single instruction.

Of course, `slct` might be used by the compiler in other cases; this is not up to you.

### 3. Effectively-avoid branches by striving for warp-wide consensus

(see also @RobertCrovella's comment to the same effect.)

Again, explanation by example.

```
 void foo(int* a, int *b) {
     ...
     if (threadIdx.x % 2 == 0) { do_stuff(); }
     else { do_other_stuff(); }
     ...
 }
```

Version 2:

```
 void foo(int* a, int *b) {
     ...
     if (threadIdx.x >= blockDim.x / 2) { do_stuff(); }
     else { do_other_stuff(); }
     ...
 }
```

This ensures that all warps, except perhaps the middle one, will either have all lanes meeting the condition or all lanes failing to meet it. And that means no lanes will in those warps will have to wait idly while other lanes execute the other branch.

For a real-life example, check out slides 7-13 in Mark Harris' [presentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) I mentioned above.